# Do separately semi-continuous functions have a dense set of semi-continuities?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, product-space, continuity, semicontinuous-functions

The connection between separate continuity and joined continuity has been studied quite a lot. In particular, one has (as a special case of a far more general Theorem from [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pjm/1102912474)) the following:

> If $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ are closed and $f\colon U\times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is separately continuous (i.e. for all $y\in V$ the map $U\ni x \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous and for all $x\in U$ the map $V\ni y \mapsto f(x,y)$ is continuous), then there is a set $A\subset U$ which is dense in $U$ and $f$ is continuous in $A\times V$.

Now for my question: Is it known whether the same holds true, if one replaces the word "continuous" with "lower semi-continuous" everywhere? Are there any results in that direction?

Comment: Possible places to begin looking: [*La mesurabilité des fonctions de deux variables et de la superposition* $F(x, f(x))$](http://pldml.icm.edu.pl/pldml/element/bwmeta1.element.zamlynska-dd41c0e6-339e-40b0-8736-170d2404d821) by Zbigniew Grande (1978) ***AND*** [*Sectionwise properties and measurability of functions of two variables*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01897318) by Miklós Laczkovich and György Petruska (1982). (Not just these papers, but also their references.)